# VBA - How to copy all data from other workbook and paste it in last row

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy the data from a workbook and paste it in the last row of the other workbook without the header.

For example:

```
Workbook1                                Workbook2
**Color** |  **Animals** |  Fruits       **Color** | **Animals**| **Fruits**               
yellow    | elephant     | apple         black     | pig        |  mango
blue      | girrafe      | banana        white     | dog        |  grapes
```

now what i want is all data from workbook will be pasted below worbk2 without the headers...

```
Workbook1
**Colors** | **Animal** | **Fruits**
yellow     | elephant   |  apple  
blue       | girrafe    |  banana
black      | pig        |  mango
white      | dog        |  grapes
```

can someone please help about this.
heres my code..

```
Public Sub sample1()

Dim file1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim file2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim CopyRange As Range

    'Open both workbooks first:
    Set file1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text)
    Set file2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text)

    Set Sheet1 = file1.Sheets(1)
    Set Sheet2 = file2.Sheets(1)

    lngLastCol = Sheet1.Cells(1, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lngLastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    varArray = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), Sheet1.Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastCol)).Value

    Set CopyRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow)
    CopyRange.EntireRow.Copy Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)

    'Now, copy what you want from :
    file1.Sheets("sheet1").CopyRange.EntireRow.Copy Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)


    'Now, paste to  worksheet:
    file2.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial

    'Close 1-2:
    file2.Save
    file1.Close
    file2.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set Sheet1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text).Sheets(1)
Set Sheet2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'assuming no blank rows/column
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count) 'exclude header

Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
              rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

Sheet2.Parent.Close True 'save changes
Sheet1.Parent.Close False 'don't save
```

Comment: i have another questions,, how can i arrange it byup-to-date if a have column date?

Comment: I would create another question for that, including more sample data

Comment: The code is working. However, I found additional blank rows exist in the "pasted" worksheet. How can it be solved?